# Angular 6: after converting JSON to array how do I display

Tags: arrays, json, angular6

I am receiving the following JSON from the db. In this case, it is only one row of data:

```
this.productsObj:  
Object { id: "8", title: "Testing prod img id", price: "9.67", category: "candles", ts: "2019-01-03 05:14:24", product_image_id: "27" }
```

I convert it to an array, so that I can use it in an ngFor loop:

```
  this.mappedProdObj = Object.keys(this.productsObj).map(key => ({
    [key]: this.productsObj[key]
  }));
```

Which returns something that looks like an array:

```
this.mappedProdObj:  
0: Object { id: "8" }
1: Object { title: "Testing prod img id" }
2: Object { price: "9.67" }
3: Object { category: "candles" }
4: Object { ts: "2019-01-03 05:14:24" }
5: Object { product_image_id: "27" }
```

I then call this mappedProdObj in an ngFor loop:

```
 <ul *ngFor="let item of mappedProdObj">
  <li>
    {{ item.title
    }}<!-- title -->
  </li>
  <li>
    {{ item.price
    }}<!-- price -->
  </li>
  <li>
    {{ item.category
    }}<!-- category -->
  </li>
  <li>
    {{ item.product_image_id
    }}<!-- product image id -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

It returns several empty unordered items from what I would expect:

```
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
Testing prod img id
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
9.67
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
candles
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
27
```

Why is this not working? And why are there eight bullet points at the end, is it because I skipped over the timestamp element?

I just would to see the following:

```
Testing prod img id
9.67
candles
27
```

Anyways, please explain to me so that I may understand how ngFor works. I have to go to the dentist to be tortured, but I will return to read your replys.

As usual, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has to go through this. The first thing is to return the JSON that is in the format:

```
{"products":[{"id":"8","name":"Testing prod img id","price":"9.67","category":"candles","ts":"2019-01-03 05:14:24","product_image_id":"27"},{"id":"9","name":"Test 2","price":"12.35","category":"chocolates","ts":"2019-01-03 12:58:50","product_image_id":"28"}]}
```

In PHP, you can do this in the following way:

```
$this->result_min = array('products'=>$this->result);
```

This places an array within an array, which gives you a type of "tree node structure", if you will, with "products" being the trunk of the tree

Then following the making of this new array, convert to JSON:

```
echo json_encode($this->result_min);
```

Which returns the above JSON structure

Within a services file, receive the JSON and make it observable:

```
 getAllProducts() {
  return new Observable(observe => {
    this.http.get<any>(this.getAllProductUrl).subscribe(resu => {
      this.getAllProductsResult = resu;
      // console.log("this.getAllProductsResult: ", this.getAllProductsResult);
      observe.next(resu);
    });
  });
}
```

In the component, with the services injected into the constructor, you subscribe to the observable - notice that it reads resProd.products - the same as the trunk of our newly constructed JSON tree node:

```
  this.prdSrvc.getAllProducts().subscribe(resProd => {
    this.productsObj = resProd.products;
    console.log("resProd.products: ", resProd.products);
  });
```

Then within the html:

```
  <ul *ngFor="let item of productsObj">
    <li>
      {{ item.name
      }}<!-- title -->
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ item.price
      }}<!-- price -->
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ item.category
      }}<!-- category -->
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ item.product_image_id
      }}<!-- product image id -->
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Of course, I will have to make this look nice, but at least it works